# Replacing char in a multiline string by preserving minimum line width

Tags: python, string

I have a multi-line string that should keep length of 3. However, white-spaces got stuck in one or more of the strings and I want to remove them:

```
s = '''123
4 56
7 8'''

print(s)

lines = s.splitlines()
for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
    for _ in range(len(line) - len('123')):
        lines[idx] = line.replace(' ', '')

s = '\n'.join(lines)
print(s)


123
4 56    # problematic line
7 8
123
456     # fixed line
7 8     # this line should not change, as the white-space here does not make the line longer than length 3
```

This gives me the desired output (i.e. **all lines have length 3 (I don't want to remove any white spaces that do not violate the length-3-rule)**, and only white-spaces were removed) but is there a better way to do so?

Comment: are you opposed to using regex ?

Comment: Not at all, but can you have a regex that checks length of line before applying?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass `count` as argument to `str.replace` to specify the maximum amount of replacement.

A list-comprehension can also be used to shorten your code.

```
s = '''123
4 56
7 8'''

lines = [line.replace(' ', '', len(line) - 3) for line in s.splitlines()]

s = '\n'.join(lines)

print(s)
```

Note that negative `count` is simply interpreted as `0`, so it is fine to use `len(line) - 3` even though it could return a negative value.

### Output

```
123
456
7 8
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach.

**Demo:**

```
s = '''123
4 56
7 8
123
456
7 8'''

print("\n".join(i.replace(' ', '') if len(i) != 3 else i for i in s.splitlines()))
```

**Output:**

```
123
456
7 8
123
456
7 8
```